# What are the replacement options for my Miche cassette?

Tags: cassette, compatibility, sprocket

I have a sprocket with chipped teeth. It's on a Miche Primato ten-speed cassette ("Fac Michelin PRIMATO 12/25", in the catalogue) with a Campagnolo Mirage groupset.

The hub is labelled Bianchi/Miche.

Is it possible to make a good guess from this information and the photo below about its compatibility?

As well as making Shimano and Campagnolo-pattern cassettes, Miche also produce their own pattern (sometimes referred to as *M-drive*, or *M* in their catalogues).

Apparently, many Bianchi-branded hubs in this era used M-drive freehub bodies, and there was at the time a Miche Primato 10-speed  M-drive cassette.

How can I be sure (without getting the cassette off) that this cassette is on a Campagnolo body and not on an M-drive body?

[image: Miche 10-speed cassette]

Comment: Is that your bike?  Appears to have 9 cogs in the cassette.   Can you point out the chipped teeth?  Sometimes, people mistake the shifting aids for damage.

Comment: There are ten sprockets on that, I can assure you! In fact I think the reason you only counted nine is because the fourth sprocket (from the front) is so badly damaged. I have no idea how that happened - I was on a ride, and that gear kept slipping. I was shocked to see so many teeth missing.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your main question specifically, I feel that your cassette, is likely a Miche Primato designed to interface with a Campagnolo freehub.

In 2007 the Mirage groupset came out as 10 speeds.  Please see [2007 Campagnolo catalog](https://www.disraeligears.co.uk/site/campagnolo_-_2007_page_33.html).  Here is a listing on a popular internet sale site for the correct [Miche Primato 10 speed Campagnolo cassette](https://www.wiggle.com/us/p/miche-primato-10-speed-cassette-campagnolo) as it fits only on a Campagnolo specific freehub body and works with all Campy 10 speed groupsets, inclusive of the Mirage.

Delving into a [Bianchi catalog from 2007](https://labibleduvelocataloguesbianchi.blogspot.com/p/bianchi-2007.html?m=1), I found a model number of Via Nirone 7 listed as Y7B44. This is an aluminum model with consistent specs with the ones you've listed.  Note that when a Bianchi bike is fitted with a Campy groupset the rear hub is listed as "fac Michelin RACING 28H." If the bike model is outfitted with Shimano Ultegra or 105, the corresponding rear hub is a Shimano WH-xxx or a Joytech hub. The letters "fac" at the beginning of the cassette (Miche PRIMATO, sure enough) as well as the wheel and rear hub likely refer to Campagnolo specific design. There are no Shimano bikes having this notation in front of the wheel or cassette model.

[image: campy specs]

So you are looking for a Campy specific version of a 10 speed cassette. PRIMATO is the direct replacement but all 10 speed Campy cassettes for Campy style freehub's would work.

Comment: I have the same question here as for the other answer: I know that it's not a Shimano-pattern cassette, but how can I be sure, without getting the cassette off, whether it has an M-drive pattern or a Campagnolo pattern?

Comment: @DanieleProcida take the cassette off - you'll need a lockring tool, a big spanner to turn it, and some way to restrain the cassette like a chain whip.   All worth owning if you maintain your bike.

Comment: @DanielleProcida I spent some time googling your question of M-spline v Campagnolo and it still isn't clear to me how to tell (if even possible) without taking the cassette off.  However, this guy may know, and I suggest you email him via the websites Contact link. [The Cycle Clinic](https://thecycleclinic.co.uk/collections/freehub-bodies#).  He is a Campagnolo pro shop and Miche dealer.

Comment: FYI, I believe that Miche cassettes should use the Campy lockring tool.

Answer (score 3):

When new, your bike should have Campagnolo hubs to go with the groupset. It is very hard to tell the difference in photos between the spline for the Campagnolo lockring tool (smaller) and the Shimano lockring tool (larger). The two sizes are so close that people can ruin lock rings by using the Campagnolo tool on Shimano lock rings. You will see a number, M27x1, stamped on the Miche lockring. This number is a metric thread size. This appears to confirm that you should order a Campagnolo compatible 10 speed cassette. Either match the gear range that you have or look up your derailleur's chain wrap and calculate what gear ranges will work. Any change in range will require a new chain or chain shortening. Unless you know that the existing chain has low wear, it would be very wise to order a new chain to go with your cassette.

Comment: Why are you sure that this is a Campagnolo-style freehub, and not a Miche-pattern freehub?

Comment: Miche makes cassettes that are compatible with Campagnolo or Shimano freehubs. One would assume that the cassette was Campagnolo but you never know on road bikes as it  sometimes happens that Shimano wheels are found on otherwise Campagnolo bikes. The only things that confirms Campagnolo is the M27 threading printed on the lockring.

Comment: I know it's not Shimano - that's not the question. The question is whether the cassette uses the Campagnolo pattern or Miche's own pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at my Miche catalogue, the Miche Primato cassette that is Bianchi specific is available in 9-speed only.

I would advise you that a 10-speed OEM fit will probably be the standard Campagnolo freehub pattern. It's easily proven (or disproven) once you release the lockring, though.

If I am wrong and you do in fact have a 10sp cass for Bianchi/Miche freehub, you'll be wanting to get a standard campag spline hub ASAP as the Bianchi/Miche spline cassettes aren't available (in the UK at least) in 10s!